# Comparing two matrices row-wise by occurrence in NumPy

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have two NumPy matrices (or Pandas DataFrames, though I'm guessing this will be faster in NumPy).

```
>>> arr1
array([[3, 1, 4],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4]])
>>> arr2
array([[3, 1, 4],
       [8, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4]])
```

For every row-vector in `arr1`, I want to count the occurrence of that row vector in `arr2` and generate a vector of these counts. So for this example, the result would be

```
[3, 0, 1, 1, 3]
```

**What is an efficient way to do this?**

*First approach*: 
The obvious approach of just using looping over the row-vectors of `arr1` and generating a corresponding boolean vector on `arr2` seems very slow.

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: (x == arr2).all(1).sum(), axis=1, arr=arr1)
```

And it seems like a bad algorithm, as I have to check the same rows multiple times.

*Second approach*: I could store the row counts in a collections.Counter, and then just access that with `apply_along_axis`.

```
cnter = Counter(tuple(row) for row in arr2)
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: cnter[tuple(x)], axis=1, arr=arr1)
```

This seems to be somewhat faster, but I feel like there has to still be a more direct approach than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a NumPy approach after converting the inputs to 1D equivalents and then sorting and using `np.searchsorted` alongwith `np.bincount` for the counting -

```
def searchsorted_based(a,b):      
    dims = np.maximum(a.max(0), b.max(0))+1

    a1D = np.ravel_multi_index(a.T,dims)
    b1D = np.ravel_multi_index(b.T,dims)

    unq_a1D, IDs = np.unique(a1D, return_inverse=1)
    fidx = np.searchsorted(unq_a1D, b1D)
    fidx[fidx==unq_a1D.size] = 0
    mask = unq_a1D[fidx] == b1D 

    count = np.bincount(fidx[mask])
    out = count[IDs]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [308]: a
Out[308]: 
array([[3, 1, 4],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4]])

In [309]: b
Out[309]: 
array([[3, 1, 4],
       [8, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4],
       [2, 1, 5]])

In [310]: searchsorted_based(a,b)
Out[310]: array([3, 0, 1, 1, 3])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [377]: A = a[np.random.randint(0,a.shape[0],(1000))]

In [378]: B = b[np.random.randint(0,b.shape[0],(1000))]

In [379]: np.allclose(comp2D_vect(A,B), searchsorted_based(A,B))
Out[379]: True

# @Nickil Maveli's soln
In [380]: %timeit comp2D_vect(A,B)
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop

In [381]: %timeit searchsorted_based(A,B)
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.6 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

***numpy:***

Start off with gathering the linear index equivalents to row and column subscripts of `a2` using `np.ravel_multi_index`. Add 1 to account for the 0-based indexing of numpy. Get the respective counts for the unique rows present through `np.unique()`. Next, find matching rows between the unique rows of `a2` and `a1` by extending `a1` to a new dimension towards the right-axis (*also known as broadcasting*) and extract indices of non-zero rows for both the arrays.

Initialize an array of zeros and fill it's values by slicing based on the obtained indices.

```
def comp2D_vect(a1, a2):
    midx = np.ravel_multi_index(a2.T, a2.max(0)+1)
    a, idx, cnt = np.unique(midx, return_counts=True, return_index=True)
    m1, m2 = (a1[:, None] == a2[idx]).all(-1).nonzero()
    out = np.zeros(a1.shape[0], dtype=int)
    out[m1] = cnt[m2]
    return out
```

***benchmarks:***

For:  **`a2 = a2.repeat(100000, axis=0)`**

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(a2, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df_count = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
df_count.reindex(a1.T.tolist(), fill_value=0).values
10 loops, best of 3: 67.2 ms per loop    # @ Ted Petrou's solution

%timeit comp2D_vect(a1, a2)
10 loops, best of 3: 34 ms per loop      # Posted solution

%timeit searchsorted_based(a1,a2)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.6 ms per loop    # @ Divakar's solution (winner)
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your explanation, thank you Nickil.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas would be a good tool for this. You can put arr2 into a dataframe and use the `groupby` method to count the number of occurences of each row and then reindex the result with arr1.

```
arr1=np.array([[3, 1, 4],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4]])

arr2 = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
       [8, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 1, 4]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr2, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df_count = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
df_count.reindex(arr1.T.tolist(), fill_value=0)
```

Output

```
a  b  c
3  1  4    3
4  3  5    0
6  5  4    1
      4    1
3  1  4    3
dtype: int64
```

**Timings**
Create a lot more data first

```
arr2_2 = arr2.repeat(100000, axis=0)
```

Now time it:

```
%%timeit
cnter = Counter(tuple(row) for row in arr2_2)
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: cnter[tuple(x)], axis=1, arr=arr1)
```

1 loop, best of 3: 704 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(arr2_2, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df_count = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
df_count.reindex(arr1.T.tolist(), fill_value=0)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 53.8 ms per loop

Comment: Thank you for this Ted, but my real concern here is just efficiency - your approach is about 20 times slower than my second approach on my machine for my example data, and scales slower as well.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't scale? Your method brute forces it with two for loops. I added some timings to a much larger dataset.

Comment: I stand corrected, my apologies. I can't really understand why this is so much faster than my Counter approach though.

Comment: Your counter approach uses two for loops. Once directly in your comprehension and again indirectly with `apply_along_axis`. My code is vectorized, uses no for loops.

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious if there's a direct way to vectorize the operation in NumPy, as to me the DataFrame overhead doesn't _feel_ like it should be necessary to vectorize it.

Comment: With that being said, if I can't find a NumPy-level solution I'll happily accept this answer as it is a massive improvement.

Comment: I don't believe numpy has any easy group by functionality. You could probably hash each row and then count the hashes. Check this thread for more detail on numpy and groupby. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7265

Comment: This seems solid, I'll do some further research but I really appreciate your help.