# Compare array wise of two 3D matrices in Numpy without for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison, vectorization

All Numpy-experts, this is probably pretty straight forward for you guys. This question should exists, but I did not found something exact solving it. Something similar was [Comparing two matrices row-wise by occurrence in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934706/comparing-two-matrices-row-wise-by-occurrence-in-numpy) and [Numpy compare array to multiple scalars at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277199/numpy-compare-array-to-multiple-scalars-at-once) but not exactly there.

I need to compute `numpy.array_equal` for a multidimensional array but I'm pretty sure I don't need to use double for-loops. However, if I would compute using double for-loops, it would look as following:

```
M = numpy.array(
     [
         [
            [1,2,3],
            [1,3,4]
         ],
         [
            [3,4,5],
            [1,2,3]
         ],
         [
            [1,2,3],
            [1,3,4]
         ]
     ])

result = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[0]))
for i in range(M.shape[0]):
    for j in range(M.shape[0]):
        result[i,j] = numpy.array_equal(M[i], M[j])
```

I should end up with a `M.shape[0]^2` large truth table, where at least the diagonal is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) after extending  -
the input to two `4D` versions such that we can compare the *pairiwise-array-blocks* against each other along the first axis while keeping the last two axes aligned -

```
result = (M[:,None] == M).all((2,3))
```

We can extend this to generic n-dim array case using last two axes as input to `.all()` -

```
(M[:,None] == M).all((-2,-1))
```

Leverage `views` to have a more memory efficient and hence performant one -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/ @Divakar
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

M1D = view1D(M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1))
result = M1D[:,None] == M1D
```

Timings on large array -

```
In [48]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: M = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100,100))

In [49]: %timeit (M[:,None] == M).all((-2,-1))
10 loops, best of 3: 92.2 ms per loop

In [50]: %%timeit 
    ...: M1D = view1D(M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1))
    ...: M1D[:,None] == M1D
1000 loops, best of 3: 627 µs per loop
```

Original one -

```
In [54]: %%timeit
    ...: result = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[0]))
    ...: for i in range(M.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(M.shape[0]):
    ...:         result[i,j] = numpy.array_equal(M[i], M[j])
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop
```

The conclusion would be - Remove loops, but watch out for memory usage. If possible, find other ways that keeps it vectorized and memory efficient.